# Why is $\pi$ not 0 when differentiated?

Tags: calculus

I'm currently a student looking through the differentiation topic and came across this problem as follows...

$$V=125\pi r-\pi r^3$$

Where   $ r$ is a variable and $r^3$ represents r cubed.

The first derivative $\frac {dV}{dr} = 125\pi-3r^2 \pi$

The second derivative $\frac {d^2V}{dr^2} = -6r\pi$

The formula and derivatives are both correct, however, my original attempt at them was the exact same apart from the exclusion of $\pi$.

If $y=57$ were to be differentiated the result would be $0$ according to Wallis' law. But as$\pi$ is simply a constant real number, why does it not simply disappear? (For lack of a better word.)

Comment: As you claim, $\pi$ is like any constant.  $\frac d{dx} Cx=C$ for any constant $C$.

Comment: $\pi$ is a factor, not a summand, therefore it does not "disppear", but stays as a factor. This is irrelevant for the exercise here, but if the factor would be negative, you would determine minimum / maximum wrong, if you would omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Let us check it out by looking at what the definition says. There is nothing mysterious.

By differentiating the function $V = 125\pi r - \pi r^{3}$ (where $\pi$ is a constant like $125$ so the value of $V$ is dependent on $r$ alone) at a point $r$ we mean taking the limit
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[125 \pi (r+h) - \pi (r+h)^{3}] - [125 \pi r - \pi r^{3}]}{h}.
$$
Now you see that $\pi$, like $125$, does not contribute anything to the differentiation of this function.

Comment: When you wanna hang out you got to take her out, cocaine...or are you not *that* Eric Clapton?